# Angular Toggle only the element click on

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have a method that toggles a div area.

At the moment I have 3 areas

app.component.ts

```
show = false;


toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="show">
      <div>One</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="show">
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="show">
      <div>Three</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>
```

At the moment is will show and hide the 3 sections.

How can I chan it so that it just toggles the div with the `*ngIf="show"` that I of the button I clicked?

Comment: Use three different boolean variables instead of one variable.

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. Is there a way to pass a parameter in toggle($event) for example and then just toggle(this) ?

Comment: Well if you are binding anything with `show` (i.e. 1 variable), then changing it will affect everywhere it is bound. If you do not want to do that then you can go with the traditional javascript approach by sending the reference of the div and changing it's style.display to `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to have three different booleans in the controller, you could look into Angular [`TemplateRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef) to create different templates for each sections.

Template

```html
<ng-template #templateOne>
  One
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateTwo>
  Two
</ng-template>

<ng-template #templateThree>
  Three
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
<br /><br />

<button type="button" (mouseup)="showRef(templateOne)">Show Template 1</button>
<button type="button" (mouseup)="showRef(templateTwo)">Show Template 2</button>
<button type="button" (mouseup)="showRef(templateThree)">Show Template 3</button>
<button type="button" (mouseup)="showRef(null)">Hide all</button>
```

Now you could set the `template` variable in the controller to the `<ng-template>` block that needs to be displayed.

```js
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;

  showRef(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.template = template;
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-templateref-ngtemplateoutlet)

Answer (score 3):

I guess below is what you want:
app.component.ts

```
toggleStatus =[false,false,false];

toggle(index:number) {
    this.toggleStatus[index] = !this.toggleStatus[index];
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="toggleStatus[0]">
      <div>One</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle(0)"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="toggleStatus[1]">
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle(1)"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="toggleStatus[2]">
      <div>Three</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle(2)"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a responsible class for doing this, with a property for each `div`:

```
class SectionVisibilityHandler {
     private boolean _div1 = false;
     private boolean _div2 = false;
     private boolean _div3 = false;

     public toggle(idx: number): boolean {
         this['_div' + idx] = !this['_div' + idx];
     }

     public get div1(): boolean {
         return this._div1;
     }

     public get div2(): boolean {
         return this._div2;
     }

     public get div3(): boolean {
         return this._div3;
     }
}
```

And then, access these properties using getters:

```
<div>
   <div *ngIf="visibilityHandler.div1">
     <div>One</div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="visibilityHandler.div2">
      <div>Two</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="visibilityHandler.div3">
      <div>Three</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" toggle()"></button>
</div>
```

And the visibility handler object is defined in your component properties:

```
public visibilityHandler: SectionVisibilityHandler = new SectionVisbilityHandler();
```

This way, you can customize your logic behind showing/hiding the div in a specific class and method.

However, you can define this class as a service and inject it inside the component.

**NOTE:** If your `div`s are dynamically generated then you need an array in the handling class and two methods, one for toggling a specific index and another one to access arrays' elements by index.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `[ngSwitch]` to solve this problem. (See stackblitz below)

#### app.component.html

```html
<nav>
  <ul style="cursor: pointer;">
    <li (click)="showTab('tab1')"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li (click)="showTab('tab2')"><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
    <li (click)="showTab('tab3')"><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="tab">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'tab1'">
    <h1>Tab 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'">
    <h1>Tab 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'tab3'">
    <h1>Tab 3</h1>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  public tab: string = "tab1";

  public showTab(tab: string) {
    this.tab = tab;
  }
}
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-snj6zw
>
> https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch